# after logout from users account all page shows error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have vb.net web application in which if users are logged in than all other pages working fine but the time I log out from account than it gets error in all pages.  I know the page getting values from cookies but if cookies is empty then it's getting null & so cause the error page

Error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

VB Code for any pageload

```
Dim var, Type As String
        var = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("chkusername").Value)
        Type = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("User_Type").Value)
        Dim LogIn, LogOut, listup As Control
        Dim BtnProfile As Button = Page.Master.FindControl("myAccount")

        LogIn = Master.FindControl("login")
        LogOut = Master.FindControl("logout")
        listup = Master.FindControl("list")

        'not login
        If HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("chkusername") Is Nothing Then
            listup.Visible = True
            LogIn.Visible = True
            LogOut.Visible = False
            BtnProfile.Visible = False

            'login
        Else
            LogOut.Visible = True
            BtnProfile.Visible = True
            LogIn.Visible = False
            listup.Visible = False

        End If
```

Login Page code

```
Dim User, Pass As String
        If selectbusinesstype.SelectedValue.ToString = "0" Then
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Select login type first');</script>")
        ElseIf selectbusinesstype.SelectedValue = "Hospitals" Then

            Try
                If loginId.Text <> "" And password.Text <> "" Then

                    Dim str As String = "select * from hospitals where username='" + loginId.Text + "' and Password='" + password.Text + "';"
                    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
                    con.Open()
                    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim ds As New DataSet
                    da.Fill(ds)
                    con.Close()
                    User = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("username")
                    Pass = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("password")

                    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

                        If User = loginId.Text.ToString And Pass = password.Text.ToString Then
                            Response.Cookies("User_Type").Value = "Hospitals"
                            Response.Cookies("chkusername").Value = loginId.Text
                            Response.Redirect("hospital-profile.aspx?user=" + Request.Cookies("chkusername").Value)
                        Else
                            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('User name or password is invalid');</script>")
                        End If
                    Else
                        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('User name or password is invalid');</script>")
                    End If
                Else
                    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Enter All the Details');</script>")
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write("<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />")
                Response.Write(ex)
                con.Close()
            End Try
```

Comment: Do you have master page? Is there anything related to user in master page load? Can you please verify?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri I have master page but there is nothing on master page load.

Comment: I see that you declared two variables in page load var and type but didn't find any usage of those variables. Also they are assigned from cookie without checking cookie is nothing or not. So can you please assign those variables only when cookie is not nothing. Please and let me know.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri can you show me example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have below lines,

```
Dim var, Type As String
var = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("chkusername").Value)
Type = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("User_Type").Value)
```

Convert it to,

```
Dim var, Type As String

If not HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("chkusername") Is Nothing Then
    var = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("chkusername").Value)
End If

If not HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("User_Type") Is Nothing Then
    Type = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("User_Type").Value)
End If
```